# ivar will not respond to NSMutableString method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, instance-variables, nsmutablestring

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Engine : NSObject {
    NSMutableString *mutableName;
}

@property (assign)  NSMutableString *mutableName;

@end
```

Why does my ivar, `engine.name` not work with this simple `NSMutableString` method? `mutableName` is an `NSMutableString` and has been correctly implemented with `@property` and `@synthesize`.

```
#import "Engine.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Engine *engine = [[Engine alloc]init];


  #import "Engine.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
Engine *engine = [[Engine alloc]init];

engine.mutableName = @"Jones";
[engine.mutableName insertString:@"Mrs." atIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Full name is %@", engine.mutableName);

}

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}

#import "Engine.h"

@implementation Engine

@synthesize mutableName;

@end

#import "Engine.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Engine *engine = [[Engine alloc]init];

    engine.mutableName = @"Jones";
    [engine.mutableName insertString:@"Mrs." atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Full name is %@", name);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never assigned anything to the `mutableName` property, so it is `nil` and ignores your method calls.

Comment: @ugho: It's possible that it is set up in `-[Engine init]` or through the `name` setter, but you're quite likely correct.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your code, but I suspect what you've done is declared both `name` and `mutableName` properties and implemented them to use the same ivar under the hood. In this case, your `mutableName` property, while declared as `NSMutableString`, is actually returning the `NSString` that was assigned to the `name` property. If this is what you're doing, and you really do want it to work this way, then you need to change your `name` accessors to look like the following (assuming `_name` is the backing ivar):

```
- (NSString *)name {
    return [[_name copy] autorelease]; // take a snapshot of the string
}
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    [_name release];
    _name = [_name mutableCopy];
}
```

This way the string is kept as mutable under the hood, but returned as an immutable string when using the `name` accessor.

Comment: please see edit above - I have now reposted all the files. So as you can see I have not declared a joint ivar. What I mean by not working is that it will not print out. Im not sure what James meant by Define: "will not work"???  would really appreciate why this simple NSMutableString method will not print out with NSLog. Thanks again

Comment: You seriously need to fix the formatting of your post. It's impossible to read. And James is right, you did not specify what you meant by "will not work". Does it do nothing? Does it throw an exception? Does it cause demons to fly out your nose?

Comment: Quite right I do apologise. Anyway Ive sorted the problem. The iVar engine.mutableName had not been fully initilized with a NSMutableString. I made a new string as follows:  NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Jones"]; and then assigned it to engine.mutableName. No demons flying out my nose ! Thanks.

Comment: _name = [name... In the setter